# Springboot - Weekdays count query

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, formula

**My Use-cases:**

- We have an installation schedule entity (check below code) and it has an installation date.
- Once installation has completed, after 4 weekdays we will verify the installation status with customers.
  Note: (4 weekdays - this count is configurable. So 'X' weekdays)

Weekdays means - Monday to Friday. We don't care about other holidays.

- I have a scheduler, it will retrieve these orders after 'X' weekdays - **I'm stuck here**

I don't know how to make a query for after 'X' weekdays.

**My code:**

```
    @Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema", name = "installation_dates")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InstallDates extends TransEntity implements Serializable {
     // other columns

    @Column(name = "installation_schedule_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime installationScheduleDatetime;//I use this column for calculation

    @Formula("getWeekDaysCount(installationScheduleDatetime)")
    private int weekDaysCount;

   
    public  int getWeekDaysCount(LocalDateTime installationScheduleDatetime) {
        int totalWeekDays = 0;
        LocalDateTime todayDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        while (!installationScheduleDatetime.isAfter(todayDate)) {
            switch (installationScheduleDatetime.getDayOfWeek()) {
                case FRIDAY:
                case SATURDAY:
                    break;
                default:
                    totalWeekDays++;
                    break;
            }

            installationScheduleDatetime = installationScheduleDatetime.plusDays(1);
        }
        return totalWeekDays;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How to make a SQL or JPQL or JPA query for weekdays?

I knew its very basic question, I am a mobile app developer, I recently joined the Springboard team, it's really hard for me :(

Feel free to give your valuable feedback!

Comment: 1. No., 2 SQL doesn't know days so I doubt it. But what prevents you from just having a `getWeekDaysCount` which calculates it on the fly (or calculates it lazily)? Why would it need to be a property.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need to use this in the query. I have a scheduler, it will fetch weekDaysCount>4. I tried your answer, but I'm not able to use this in my query

Comment: Even with an `@Formula` that wouldn't work. How are you going to account for (banking) holidays? So instead of describing what you tried (and failed) explain your use-case. You probably need a view or a custom SQL query to do the calculation, JPA isn't going to help here.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, now I understand. Formula & JPA isn't the right solution. I updated my use-case in my question. We will ignore holidays, I need to calculate weekdays (Mon - Fri)

Comment: just to clarify, you want something like "give me all installations which were done X workdays ago"?

Comment: @vladtkachuk yes, exactly. I want all installation dates

Comment: @Ranjithkumar I posted an answer, pls have a look if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a following suggestion if I correctly got the problem.

Java:

1. Take the current date
2. Find the `date of interest`: count minus 4 workdays (so if it is Friday today - subtract 4 days, if it is Monday - subtract 2 days for weekend and 4 more days for weekdays)

Then write a query that will select all installations that were done on the date of interest.
In pseudo code:
`select * from installations where installation_date = <date of interest>;`.

**Date of interest Java code:**

```
public LocalDateTime getDateOfInterest(int workdays) {
    LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    if (workdays < 1) {
        return currentDate;
    }

    //it will subtract 'X' working days from current date
    LocalDateTime result = currentDate;
    int addedDays = 0;
    while (addedDays < workdays) {
        result = result.minusDays(1);
        if (!(result.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ||
                result.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)) {
            ++addedDays;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Cool, would be interesting to know. The key idea behind my thinking was to separate what should be done on DB level and what is easier/possible to do in Java.

Comment: Tested & it works. I added my calculation code. It will helpful in future.

Answer (score 0):

First lets answer your questions

1. No you cannot call a method from `@Formula`
2. You probably could (see [here](https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/find-working-days-between-two-dates-in-sql-server/) but that might depend on your database.

The fact that you use an entity and JPA doesn't mean **everything** has to be a JPA property.

You could:

1. Write a get method that calculates it on the fly
2. Write a getter which sets it lazily.
3. Use the `@PostLoad` to always set it.

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema", name = "installation_dates")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InstallDates extends TransEntity implements Serializable {
     // other columns

    @Column(name = "installation_schedule_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime installationScheduleDatetime;//I use this column for calculation
  
    public int getWeekDaysCount() {
        int totalWeekDays = 0;
        LocalDateTime isdt = this.installationScheduleDatetime;
        LocalDateTime todayDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        while (!isdt.isAfter(todayDate)) {
            switch (isdt.getDayOfWeek()) {
                case FRIDAY:
                case SATURDAY:
                    break;
                default:
                    totalWeekDays++;
                    break;
            }
            isdt = isdt.plusDays(1);
        }
        return totalWeekDays;
    }
}
```

Or if you really want it to be a property, you could use the getter to set it lazily.

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema", name = "installation_dates")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InstallDates extends TransEntity implements Serializable {
     // other columns

    @Column(name = "installation_schedule_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime installationScheduleDatetime;//I use this column for calculation
  
    private int weekDaysCount = -1;

    public int getWeekDaysCount() {
      if (weekDaysCount == -1) {
        int totalWeekDays = 0;
        LocalDateTime isdt = this.installationScheduleDatetime;
        LocalDateTime todayDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        while (!isdt.isAfter(todayDate)) {
            switch (isdt.getDayOfWeek()) {
                case FRIDAY:
                case SATURDAY:
                    break;
                default:
                    totalWeekDays++;
                    break;
            }
            isdt = isdt.plusDays(1);
        }
        weekDaysCount = totalWeekDays;
      }
      return weekDaysCount;
    }
}
```

Or if you always want to calculate that value you could even place it in an `@PostLoad` annotation on a method to initialize it (you could even reuse the above lazy getter for it). Or move the init code to the `@PostLoad` annotated method.

```java
@PostLoad
private void initValues() {
  getWeekDaysCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Formula` specifies an **expression written in native SQL** that is used to read the value of an attribute instead of storing the value in a Column. (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html)

As for your case, it doesn't look like there's much use in storing `weekDaysCount` in the DB if it's derived from `installationScheduleDatetime`. I'd just mark the `weekDaysCount` as `@Transient` and be done with it (`@Formula` should be removed).

Another solution would be to leave `weekDaysCount` non-transient and put your calculations in a `@PreUpdate/@PrePersist` method. See https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events for more info on that.